# passing aws creds to kitchen ec2 command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, chef-infra

I am trying to do chef cookbook development via Jenkinsfile pipeline. I have my jenkins server running as a container (using jenkinsci/blueocean image). As one of the stages, I am trying to do aws configure and then run kitchen test. For some reason with below code, I am getting unauthorized operation error. For some reason, my AWS creds are not sent properly to .kitchen.yml (No need to check IAM creds, because they have admin access)

```
stage('\u27A1 Verify Kitchen') {
        steps { 
            sh '''mkdir -p ~/.aws/
echo 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...' >> ~/.aws/credentials
echo 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...' >> ~/.aws/credentials
cat ~/.aws/credentials
KITCHEN_LOCAL_YAML=.kitchen.yml /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/kitchen list
KITCHEN_LOCAL_YAML=.kitchen.yml /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/kitchen test'''
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway, I can pass AWS creds here. Also .kitchen.yml no longer supports passing AWS creds inside the file. Is there someway I can pass creds on command i.e. .kitchen.yml access_key=... secret_access_key=... /opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/kitchen test 
Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to set `KITCHEN_LOCAL_YAML=.kitchen.yml`, that's already the primary config file.
2. You probably want to be using a Jenkins credential file, not hardcoding things into the job. But that said, the reason this isn't working is because the AWS `credentials` file is not a shell script, which is the syntax you're using there. It's an INI/TOML file and is paired with a similar `config` file that shares a similar structure.
3. You should probably just be using the environment variable support in kitchen-ec2 via the `withEnv` pipeline helper method or similar things for integrating with Jenkins managed credentials.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger I couldn't figure this out at the end and using bitbucket pipelines to do this testing (: